# Apollo GraphQL Client: Local and Remote State Patterns

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using `react-apollo` and I'd like to better understand how to manage a `type` that can exist locally or remotely.

For example, let's say I had a `Category` type.

```
type Category {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

1. I'd like to be able to `query` existing instances of my `Category` types from my remote server.
2. I'd then like to be able to `create`, `update`, and `delete` instances locally.
3. I'd like to persist the changes to my `remote` server when the user performs a "Done" action.

I've seen examples of how to add and query additional fields using the `@client` directive, but it's unclear to me how to manage entire instances that can live either locally or remotely.

Any suggestions of patterns, resources, etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is an interesting problem, although I'm not sure Apollo local state is the best vehicle for what you need. It's really meant for state that's independent of your server-side data or, at most, [co-located with it](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state#client-with-remote-queries). Using it to effectively orchestrate a series of mutations, or somehow sync local and remote data might be outside its current capabilities. I would definitely be interested to see if anyone's done something like that though!